# Не проходит проверка на наличие логина в БД (не судите строго только учусь)

Tags: c#, mysql

При проверке на налчие логина в бд, не выдает уведомление пользователь с таким логином уже найден, подскажите в каком направление смотреть... Спасибо заранее

private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        if(userNameField.Text == "Введите имя")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите имя");
            return;
        }

        if (userSernameField.Text == "Введите фамилию")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите фамилию");
            return;
        }
        
        if(loginField.Text == "Введите логин")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите логин");
            return;
        }   

        if (passField.Text == "Введите пароль")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите пароль");
            return;
        }

        if (IsUserExists())
            return;

        DB db = new DB();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `pass`, `name`, `surname`) VALUES (@login, @pass, @name, @surname )", db.GetConnection());


        command.Parameters.Add("@login", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginField.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passField.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userNameField.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@surname", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userSernameField.Text;

        db.OpenCennection();

        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Регистрация успешна");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Данные не верны");

        db.CloseConnection();


    }

    public Boolean IsUserExists()
    {
        {
            DB db = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 'login' = @uL", db.GetConnection());


            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginField.Text;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);


            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Пользователь с таким логином уже найден");
                return true;
            }

            else
               return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вероятно наличие пробельных символов. Всегда делайте `Trim` перед вставкой в БД.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, дело в этом запросе:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE 'login' = @uL", db.GetConnection());
```

Здесь `login` взят в одинарные кавычки, и поэтому MySQL подставляет не значение поля `login`, а просто строку `'login'`. (И получается функция вернёт true, только когда кто-то введёт логин `login`)

То есть, надо просто убрать кавычки:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE login = @uL", db.GetConnection());
```